# Panel data regression with fixed effects using Python

Tags: python, statistics, regression, statsmodels, linearmodels

I have the following panel stored in `df`:

|  | state | district | year | y | constant | x1 | x2 | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01 | 01001 | 2009 | 12 | 1 | 0.956007 | 639673 | 1 |
| 1 | 01 | 01001 | 2010 | 20 | 1 | 0.972175 | 639673 | 2 |
| 2 | 01 | 01001 | 2011 | 22 | 1 | 0.988343 | 639673 | 3 |
| 3 | 01 | 01002 | 2009 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 33746 | 1 |
| 4 | 01 | 01002 | 2010 | 1 | 1 | 0.225071 | 33746 | 2 |
| 5 | 01 | 01002 | 2011 | 5 | 1 | 0.450142 | 33746 | 3 |
| 6 | 01 | 01003 | 2009 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 45196 | 1 |
| 7 | 01 | 01003 | 2010 | 5 | 1 | 0.427477 | 45196 | 2 |
| 8 | 01 | 01003 | 2011 | 9 | 1 | 0.854955 | 45196 | 3 |

- `y` is the number of protests in each district
- `constant` is a column full of ones
- `x1` is the proportion of the district's area covered by a mobile network provider
- `x2` is the population count in each district (note that it is fixed in time)

How can I run the following model in Python?
[image: model]

---

Here's what I tried

```py
# Transform `x2` to match model
df['x2'] = df['x2'].multiply(df['time'], axis=0)
# District fixed effects
df['delta'] = pd.Categorical(df['district'])
# State-time fixed effects
df['eta'] = pd.Categorical(df['state'] + df['year'].astype(str))
# Set indexes
df.set_index(['district','year'])

from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS
m = PanelOLS(dependent=df['y'], exog=df[['constant','x1','x2','delta','eta']])
```

> ValueError: exog does not have full column rank. If you wish to proceed with model estimation irrespective of the numerical accuracy of coefficient estimates, you can set rank_check=False.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dug around [the documentation](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/panel/panel/linearmodels.panel.model.PanelOLS.html#linearmodels.panel.model.PanelOLS) and the solution turned out to be quite simple.

After setting the indexes and turning the fixed effect columns to `pandas.Categorical` types (see question above):

```py
# Import model
from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS

# Model
m = PanelOLS(dependent=df['y'],
             exog=df[['constant','x1','x2']],
             entity_effects=True,
             time_effects=False,
             other_effects=df['eta'])
m.fit(cov_type='clustered', cluster_entity=True)
```

That is, **DO NOT** pass your fixed effect columns to  `exog`.

You should pass them to `entity_effects` (boolean), `time_effects` (boolean) or `other_effects` (pandas.Categorical).

Comment: Thanks, are you saying that "delta" in this example should not go in "exog" but that it should go in "other_effects"?

Comment: No. Delta are the "individuals" if you may. Hence, you make delta the index and set `entity_effects = True`. In my example, `eta` is passed as `other_effects`.

Comment: Thank you. How could I see the formula of the model? I tried "mod.formula". It ran but nothing happens

Comment: Perhaps you could try `print(mod.formula)`, but to be honest I don't know.

Comment: You can only see the formula when you create a model using the formula interface (e.g. `PanelOLS.from_formula`).  If you create it using `DataFrame`s then there is no formula.